# How to extract std::string from simdjson::dom::object iterator in c++?

Tags: c++, json, string, string-view

I am trying to parse a JSON I retrieve from an API and extract string values. I have no problem to retrieve the JSON, parse it and to print out values to the standard output using `string_view`. However, I cannot manage to take the `string_view` and make it usable later on, for example by concatinate it with another string, to use it in a `std::regex` object. My code:

```
std::string json_string_body;

/* ** json_string_body is populated by the result of the http request, leaving this aside for simplicity ** */

simdjson::dom::parser parser;
simdjson::dom::element known_files = parser.parse(simdjson::padded_string(json_string_body));

for (simdjson::dom::object data_file : known_files)
{   
    std::cout << std::string_view(data_file["file_name"]) << std::endl;
    // program crashes here
    std::string df_file_name = std::string(std::string_view(data_file["file_name"]).data());
    std::string df_id = std::string(std::string_view(data_file["id"]).data());
    std::regex regex_txt(".*" + df_file_name);
    std::cout << "break1" << std::endl;
    if (std::regex_match(file_to_find, regex_txt))
{
    /* ** some more logic ** */
}
```

The code compiles, however the program crashes when trying to create the strings, as in the comment above.

```
foobar.txt // <- this is the correct field, all good with the json parsing thus far...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'simdjson::simdjson_error'
  what():  The JSON element does not have the requested type.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My questions:

- How do I correctly extract a string when using simdjson? There are dedicated functions for integers and doubles, but not for strings it seems.
- I read in the simdjson documentation that string_view should be used for printing strings. I then read elsewhere that you can create a string out of a string_view, as I did below. Again, this compiles, but then crashes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to trap this exception, what did the backtrace show?

Comment: I must confess.. I don't know how to use a debugger.. hoping someone familiar with the library would know how to correctly parse a string (or convert string_view to string).

Comment: Well, now is an excellent opportunity to learn how to use one! If you are hoping to become a skilled with C++ you have no choice but to learn how to use a debugger. You cannot expect to implement any C++ program of any moderate complexity without having to debug the code. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions, and, as an extra bonus: it won't be necessary ask someone else what's wrong with your code, you can simply figure it out yourself, every time!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You're right.. I took some time to understand some basics of GDB, which is actually not as complicated as I thought. After some digging, I realized that there are actually 2 mistakes in the code: a) ```std::string df_id = std::string(std::string_view(data_file["id"]).data());``` is an int and b) I changed ```simdjson::dom::object data_file``` to ```simdjson::dom::element data_file``` and all works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to congratulate yourself, since `gdb` is often looked down as a crude, bare-bones, and archaic debugger that's often considered to be beneath the dignity of C++ elitists who employ flashy GUI-based debuggers, with pretty buttons and menus, to work things out. But, gdb is available everywhere. On the other hand, if one only knows how to use a particular flashy GUI-based debugger, with pretty buttons and menus, and one happens not to be available on whatever they're using now, they'll be stuck like a fish out of water.